# Restrict access to specific folder on samba

Tags: server, security, samba

I have network server on ubuntu server with Samba. I want to set a password to a specific folder.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to add a new user for that folder with different password ofc.:

Below is an example with user *secretuser*:

Add user and set password:

> useradd secretuser
>    passwd secretuser

Add samba user:

> smbpasswd -a secretuser

Add a user to a Samab share:

> [accounts]
>   comment = Accounts data directory
>   path = /path/to/folder
>   valid users = user1 user2 secretuser
>   public = no
>   writable = yes

Restart the samba:

> service smb restart